# Python Web Scraping Randomly Failing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to make a sitemap for the following website:

http://aogweb.state.ak.us/WebLink/0/fol/12497/Row1.aspx

The code goes through and first determines how many pages are on the top directory level, then it stores the each page number and its corresponding link. Then it goes through each page and creates a dictionary that contains each 3 digit file value and the corresponding link for that value. From there the code takes creates another dictionary of the pages and links for each 3 digit directory (this is the point at which I am stuck). Once this is complete the goal is to create a dictionary that contains each 6 digit file number and its corresponding link.

However, the code randomly fails at certain points throughout the scraping process and gives the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scraping_Test.py", line 76, in <module>
    totalPages = totalPages.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Sometimes the code does not even run and automatically skips to the end of the program without any errors.

I am currently running python 3.6.0 and using all updated libraries on Visual Studio Community 2015. Any help will be appreciated as I am new to programming.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import re
import time



def stop():
    print('sleep 5 sec')
    time.sleep(5)

url0 = 'http://aogweb.state.ak.us'
url1 = 'http://aogweb.state.ak.us/WebLink/'


r = requests.get('http://aogweb.state.ak.us/WebLink/0/fol/12497/Row1.aspx')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
print('Status: ' + str(r.status_code))
stop()

pagesTopDic = {}
pagesTopDic['1'] = '/WebLink/0/fol/12497/Row1.aspx'
dig3Dic = {}
for link in soup.find_all('a'):             #find top pages
    if not link.get('title') is None:
        if 'page' in link.get('title').lower():
            page = link.get('title')
            page = page.split(' ')[1]
            #print(page)
            pagesTopDic[page] = link.get('href')

listKeys = pagesTopDic.keys()

for page in listKeys:                       #on each page find urls for beggining 3 digits
    url = url0 + pagesTopDic[page]
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    print('Status: ' + str(r.status_code))
    stop()

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if not link.get("aria-label") is None:
            folder = link.get("aria-label")
            folder = folder.split(' ')[0]
            dig3Dic[folder] = link.get('href')

listKeys = dig3Dic.keys()
pages3Dic = {}
for entry in listKeys: #pages for each three digit num
    print(entry)
    url = url1 + dig3Dic[entry]
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    print('Status: ' + str(r.status_code))
    stop()

    tmpDic = {}
    tmpDic['1'] = '/Weblink/' + dig3Dic[entry]


    totalPages = soup.find('div',{"class": "PageXofY"})
    print(totalPages)
    totalPages = totalPages.text
    print(totalPages)
    totalPages = totalPages.split(' ')[3]
    print(totalPages)
    while len(tmpDic.keys()) < int(totalPages):

        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        print('Status: ' + str(r.status_code))
        stop()

        for link in soup.find_all('a'):             #find top pages
            if not link.get('title') is None:
                #print(link.get('title'))
                if 'Page' in link.get('title'):
                    page = link.get('title')
                    page = page.split(' ')[1]
                    tmpDic[page] = link.get('href')
        num = len(tmpDic.keys())
        url = url0 + tmpDic[str(num)]

    print()
    pages3Dic[entry] = tmpDic
```

Comment: Did it occur to you that in some pages, for the expression: `totalPages = soup.find('div',{"class": "PageXofY"})`, totalPages is None because no div with `.PageXofY` was found?

Comment: totalPages is returning None, so it is causing errors

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. The problem was due to the website switching to an error page after a certain number of requests.